# Django filter liked Posts by User

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="liked_by", blank=True)
```

I am trying to query all posts that are liked by a particular user but I couldn't find the right __ query for it.
This is the query I'm trying to make.

```
Post.objects.filter(likes__liked_by=User.objects.get(pk=1))
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is this django-orm?

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `prefetch_related` and perform query as the below one.

```
User.objects.prefetch_related('liked_by').get(pk=1).liked_by.all()
```

Comment: It works but what's the difference between this or @RBowen's answer?

Comment: You don't need to do prefetch_related here, it's an optimisation that you would use more if querying multiple records

Comment: django will perform the separate queries, if we do something as.

`user = user.objects.get(pk=1)`
`user.liked_by.all()`

One to get the user and then the other one to get all its related posts.
But, if we use `prefetch_related` it will perform only query with the join in it.

You can check by having a look at the queried User's object dict.

`user.__dict__`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at it the opposite way so go through the

```
User.objects.get(pk=1).liked_by.all()
```